# QTableView selectionChanged

Tags: qt, qt4, selection

I have a `QTableView` that I need to get the selectionChanged event from. I can't seem to get the connect working. I have:

**MyWidget.h**

...

```
protected slots:
 void slotLoadTransaction(const QItemSelection & selected, const QItemSelection & deselected);
private:
 QTableView table;
```

...

**MyWidget.cpp**

...

```
 connect(
  table->selectionModel(),
  SIGNAL(selectionChanged(const QItemSelection & selected, const QItemSelection & deselected)),
  this,
  SLOT(slotLoadTransaction(const QItemSelection & selected, const QItemSelection & deselected))
 );
```

...

At runtime, I get "No such Signal" errors.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to remove the variable names from the SIGNAL and SLOT macros:

```
 connect(
  table->selectionModel(),
  SIGNAL(selectionChanged(const QItemSelection &, const QItemSelection &)),
  SLOT(slotLoadTransaction(const QItemSelection &, const QItemSelection &))
 );
```

Connect is essentially looking at the function signature and the variable names confuse it.

Comment: +1 You seem to have forgottent the "this" in your statement (the parameter between SIGNAL and SLOTS) tho, didn't you ?

Comment: Andy, I think I can figure that little bit out.

Kaleb, thank you sir! Works like a jewel :)

Comment: @Andy - No, I purposefully left it out.  The above syntax is more concise and equivalent whenever the recipient is "this." There are two connects, a connect instance method (which I used) and a static method. See the docs for more information.

Comment: @Andy: He didn't actually forget the "this"... if you inherit from a QObject, you have an overloaded version of connect that takes the parameters given, and assumes "this" as the object for the slot.