# Qt: problem with QTableWidget::cellClicked signal/slot not found

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots, qtablewidget

I have a QTableWidget, if a cell is clicked, I want to emit a signal to the MainWindow.

My Header File:

```
QTableWidget *myQtableWidget= new QTableWidget;
...
private slots:
    void on_myTableWidgetWindow_cellClicked(int row, int column);
```

mainWindow.cpp (in the constructor of the mainWindow):

```
connect(this->myQtableWidget, SIGNAL(cellClicked(int row, int column)),
        this, SLOT(on_myTableWidgetWindow_cellClicked(int row, int column)));
```

mainWindow.cpp (somewhere):

```
void mainWindow::on_myTableWidgetWindow_cellClicked(int row, int column)
{
//do something
}
```

The console output is:

```
QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_myTableWidgetWindow_cellClicked(int,int)
QObject::connect: No such signal QTableWidget::cellClicked(int row, int column) in ..\myProg\windowMain.cpp:71
QObject::connect:  (receiver name: 'mainWindow')
```

Why is the console telling me : "No such signal QTableWidget::cellClicked"?
In the QT-Docs, this signal is listed: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#cellClicked

I can't see my mistake, can anyone help?
best,

Comment: It should be `connect(this->myQtableWidget, SIGNAL(cellClicked(int, int)), this, SLOT(on_myTableWidgetWindow_cellClicked(int, int)));` instead. No need to include the functions parameters names.

Comment: Better still, use the new [`Qt5` signal/slot syntax](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax) -- `connect(this->myQtableWidget, &QTableWidget::cellClicked, this, &MainWindow::on_myTableWidgetWindow_cellClicked)`.

Comment: ... and [QTableView selectionChanged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376052/qtableview-selectionchanged)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you can simply get rid "row" and "column". I mean:

```
connect(this->myQtableWidget, SIGNAL(cellClicked(int, int)), 
        this, SLOT(on_myTableWidgetWindow_cellClicked(int, int)));
```